# How to Create a TouchEvent in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch, dom-events

The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#idl-def-TouchEvent) declares `initTouchEvent` as following:

```
void initTouchEvent (in DOMString    type,
                     in boolean      canBubble,
                     in boolean      cancelable,
                     in AbstractView view,
                     in long         detail,
                     in boolean      ctrlKey,
                     in boolean      altKey,
                     in boolean      shiftKey,
                     in boolean      metaKey,
                     in TouchList    touches,
                     in TouchList    targetTouches,
                     in TouchList    changedTouches);
```

However, when I try it in Chrome 44:

```
var e = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
e.initTouchEvent("touchstart", true, true, window, 1,
                 false, false, false, false, touches, null, null);
```

where `touches` is a valid `TouchList`, this is what Chrome created:

```
> TouchEvent {}
    altKey: false
    bubbles: true
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: true
    changedTouches: null
    charCode: 0
    ctrlKey: true
    currentTarget: null
    defaultPrevented: false
    detail: 0
    eventPhase: 0
    keyCode: 0
    layerX: 0
    layerY: 0
    metaKey: false
    pageX: 0
    pageY: 0
    path: Array[0]
    returnValue: true
    shiftKey: false
    srcElement: null
    target: null
    targetTouches: null
    timeStamp: 1435339572699
    touches: null
    type: "[object Window]"
    view: null
    which: 0
```

Look closely at the `type` field. Seems like Chrome is not following the spec where the 4th parameter turned into the type instead of the 1st parameter.

This brings us the question, that how do I actually create a `TouchEvent` in Chrome since it does not follow the spec?

Comment: `initTouchEvent()` is not documented on MDN or (as far as I can see) on W3C, so it's hard to find out what is actually going on here.

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery or something of the sort?

Comment: It is documented on W3C (the link is in the question). Furthermore jQuery can't help me on this because jQuery dispatches "fake" internal events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the [Chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/events/TouchEvent.cpp&q=initTouchEvent&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=58) and [Qiita (in Japanese)](http://qiita.com/damele0n/items/dc312bbf66da1d46dd6f#inittouchevent---chrome-opera-%E7%B7%A8), this seems like how its parameters are arranged:

```
initTouchEvent (TouchList touches,
                TouchList targetTouches,
                TouchList changedTouches,
                String type,
                Window view,
                number screenX,
                number screenY,
                number clientX,
                number clientY,
                boolean ctrlKey, 
                boolean altKey,
                boolean shiftKey,
                boolean metaKey);
```

Notice Chrome does not follow the W3C spec.

---

Relevant part in the Chromium source:

**`TouchEvent.cpp` Line 63:**

```
void TouchEvent::initTouchEvent(ScriptState* scriptState, TouchList* touches, TouchList* targetTouches,
        TouchList* changedTouches, const AtomicString& type,
        PassRefPtrWillBeRawPtr<AbstractView> view,
        int, int, int, int,
        bool ctrlKey, bool altKey, bool shiftKey, bool metaKey)
{
    if (dispatched())
        return;

    if (scriptState->world().isIsolatedWorld())
        UIEventWithKeyState::didCreateEventInIsolatedWorld(ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey);

    bool cancelable = true;
    if (type == EventTypeNames::touchcancel)
        cancelable = false;

    initUIEvent(type, true, cancelable, view, 0);

    m_touches = touches;
    m_targetTouches = targetTouches;
    m_changedTouches = changedTouches;
    m_ctrlKey = ctrlKey;
    m_altKey = altKey;
    m_shiftKey = shiftKey;
    m_metaKey = metaKey;
}
```