# Cloning and re-dispatching `TouchEvent` in Android system WebView

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, webview

I am trying to handle a `TouchEvent` by re-dispatching it to another DOM element. Everything works perfectly on iOS and desktop browsers with touch simulation using the following code:

```
onTouched(event: TouchEvent) {
  this.targetElement.getNativeElement()
    .dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent(event.type, event));
}
```

However, I can't get this working on Android device. I tried with a mobile phone and simulator. The problem lies in the code constructing a `TouchEvent`.

Here is what I tried:

1. `new TouchEvent(event.type, event)`
   gives `Illegal constructor` error
2. `new event.constructor(event.type, event)` gives `Illegal constructor` error
3. I tried to strip `event` from all other fields other than `touches` to fit Typescript's [`TouchEventInit` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/pull/226/files):

   ```
   let touchArr: Touch[] = [];
   for (var _i = 0; _i < event.touches.length; _i++) {
     touchArr[_i] = event.touches[_i];      
   }

   let newEvent = new TouchEvent(event.type, <TouchEventInit>{
     touches: touchArr      
   });
   ```

   but it still gives `Illegal constructor` exception.
4. In the act of desperation, I tried to use a deprecated `document.createEvent`:

   ```
   let newEvent: any = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
   newEvent.initTouchEvent(event);
   ```

   However, the `initTouchEvent` does not set the `type` for some reason (probably because of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079014/how-to-create-a-touchevent-in-chrome)) and it shouldn't be used anyway as it's [going to be removed](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/chrome-49-deprecations#use_of_inittouchevent_is_deprecated).

I am simply out of ideas. I tried with the newest Android System WebView (60.0.3112.116). I could understand this to happen on a desktop browser, but it's a mobile device...